# CALayerInvalidGeometry: CALayer position contains NaN when trying to size a small, remote svg with variable size and aspect ratio

Tags: svg, swift3, uiwebview, calayer

What I want to achieve:
Display small, variable sized svgs in my app with auto layout.
The svgs contain pre-rendered latex formulas. The svgs are loaded asynchronously so I don't know upfront which size or aspect ratio they are.

The hardest pre-conditions I could imagine.

I tried several svg displaying libraries, and no one turned out to work with our svgs, so I decided to use a UIWebView.
The problem here is, that the svgs should not be scrollable and the UIWebView of minimal size.
The svgs should span all available width and have a height based on the aspect ratio.

What I tried:

```
class FormulaView: UIView, UIWebViewDelegate, XMLParserDelegate {

private var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var topMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!

private var width = -1.0
private var height = -1.0

// MARK: Initialisation
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setUpView()
}

// MARK: Set Up
// Performs the initial setup.
// Loads a XIB file into a view and returns this view.

func loadSVG(fromURL url: URL) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url)
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}

func loadSVG(fromString string: String) {
    let url = URL(string: string)
    if url == nil {
        self.isHidden = true
        return
    }
    self.loadSVG(fromURL: url!)
}
var tableView: UITableView?

private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return view
}

private func setUpView() {
    view = viewFromNibForClass()
    view.frame = bounds

    // Auto-layout stuff.
    view.autoresizingMask = [
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
        UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
    ]
    addSubview(view)
    // Formula should take no space if no formula is loaded
    topMargin.constant = 0
    bottomMargin.constant = 0

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    ])
}

// MARK: - UIWebView delegate
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    // Get xml of svg file
    let xml = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    let parser = XMLParser(data: (xml?.data(using: .utf8))!)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

// MARK: - XMLParser delegate
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    // Get width and height of svg
    if elementName == "svg" {
        self.height = Double(attributeDict["height"]?
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "pt", with: "") ?? "")
            ?? -1.0
        self.width = Double(attributeDict["width"]?
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "pt", with: "") ?? "")
            ?? -1.0
        let aspectRatio = self.width / self.height

        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        // Calculate height the webview should have based on the width and the normal aspect ratio of the svg
        let webviewHeight = self.webView.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(aspectRatio)

        if let constraint = (webView.constraints.filter {
            $0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute
            }.first) {
            constraint.constant = webviewHeight
        } else {
            webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: webviewHeight).isActive = true
        }
        // Apply a 24 margin as a svg is now loaded
        topMargin.constant = 24
        bottomMargin.constant = 24
        tableView?.endUpdates()

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        // Zoom webview appropriately that the svg is completely visible and no scrolling is neccessary or even possible
        let scrollView = webView.scrollView
        let zoom = webView.bounds.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = zoom
        scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true) // Error occurs here
        // prevent scrolling
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    }
}
}
```

This version seems to work fine as I tested it on the simulator,
but in some cases **(EDIT: I only see these crashes in our Bug reporting tool)**, I get an error (`CALayerInvalidGeometry: CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]`) at this line `scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)`.

It seems the calculating the `zoom` results in `CGFloat.nan`,

(1) but when does this occur,

(2) how can I prevent this and

(3) if it occurs, how can I calculate the zoom in these cases?

**EDIT:** Or in other words, why are `webView.bounds.size.width` and/or `scrollView.contentSize.width` non positiv values?

If I could reproduce it, I could say more, but unluckily I can't...

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Comment: While I don't know Swift, just from reading the code it strikes me as odd that in `func parser` you seem to be defining a default value of `-1.0` for the SVG width/height. In addition, can you exclude that the SVG sizes contain other units like `%` or `px`?

Comment: Yes, I can exclude other units than `pt`.

Comment: And I've rewritten my code so I don't have an optional, but doesn't fix the problem.